# Как отобразить потомков (не только прямых) по условию, где на входе ID родителя

Tags: sql, sql-server

Существует таблица вида:

[image: Таблица MS SQL]

Для наглядности:

[image: Дерево]

Есть необходимость вывести потомков для родителя (по id родителя). Т.е. в результате должны участвовать только записи из результата:

```
SELECT id, name, parent_id
FROM dbo.test2
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT parent_id FROM dbo.test2)
```

Но как мне выводить потомков для конкретного родителя (не обязательно прямого) по id родителя (это, к сожалению, обязательное условие), т.е. если в условие поступает `WHERE id = 1` (для "Задача1"), то отобразить записи

```
стена
забор
```

если в условие поступает `WHERE id = 2` (для "покраска"), то так же отобразить записи

```
стена
забор
```

если, к примеру, в условие поступает `WHERE id = 6` (для "монтаж"), то отобразить

```
люстра
гардина
проводка
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону рекурсивные запросов, например как тут [Understanding SQL Server recursive CTE](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/)

Comment: С помощью данного рекурсивного запроса всё получилось `WITH cte_tmp AS (
    SELECT       
        id, 
        name,
        parent_id        
    FROM
        dbo.test2
    WHERE parent_id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        e.id, 
        e.name,
        e.parent_id
    FROM 
        dbo.test2 e
        INNER JOIN cte_tmp o 
            ON o.id = e.parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM cte_tmp WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT parent_id FROM dbo.test2);`